# elasticsearch scan/scroll not works when use multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

My scan/scroll is working fine with one index:

```
http://localhost:9200/2014-07-10/picture/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=1m
```

So, now I'm trying to do the same thing but using multiple indexes.

```
http://localhost:9200/2014-07-*/picture/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=1m
```

This is returning a huge scroll_id:

```
{
     "_scroll_id": "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",
     "took": 15,
     "timed_out": false,
     "_shards": {
          "total": 129,
          "successful": 129,
          "failed": 0
     },
     "hits": {
          "total": 6562,
          "max_score": 0,
          "hits": []
     }
}
```

So, when I try to scroll with this scroll_id, it returns CONN_REFUSED and creshes the server.

Is this a problem? Maybe performance issue? Or scanning on multiple indexes is not possible?